# Nested forms in JHipster

Tags: angular, jhipster, spring-rest

I am new to the JHipster stack (and Spring in general) and I want to create an app in which the "children" of OneToMany and ManyToOne relationships are created/edited in the same form (from the users perspective) as their parent.

It's a common pattern that we all are familiar with. Imagine a Person having multiple Addresses or an Invoice having multiple Items and the parent and child are so tightly coupled in the domain that it only makes sense to create them together.

```
entity Invoice
entity InvoiceItem

relationship ManyToOne {
    InvoiceItem{invoice} to Invoice
}
```

With JHipster 4.11.1 using Angular(4) and a Postgres or MySQL database, what steps do I need to take to solve this in the best possible way?

I can imagine doing this with client-side code only by simply posting to the auto-generated endpoints like /invoice /invoice-items, but it seems to me that it would put too much business logic scripting on the client side.

Should I nest specific child endpoints on my InvoiceResource or make the existing create and update endpoints accept related data somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it server-side by defining a DTO manually that combines parent and children, keep the same endpoint for parent and manage the relationship in service, delete the the child endpoint.
This is an aggregate in DDD.